Why does the result of the step potential not hold for macroscopic objects?
In quantum mechanics, the transmission probability for a particle reaching a step potential barrier less than the particle's own energy is given by:
$$
4k/(k+1)^2
$$
where
$$
k=\sqrt{E/(E-V)}
$$
with $E$ being the particle's energy and V being the potential energy of the barrier. I've factored out the mass and Planck's constant terms.
My question is, what's the limiting principle that prevents this from applying to macroscopic objects? There's no mass dependence and the energy dependence is just concerned with the ratio of the particle's energy to that of the barrier (rather than the absolute value of either).
The only thing I can think of is decoherence, that if you continually measure a wavepacket as it passes through such a barrier the reflection probability will become arbitrarily small. But I don't know how to justify this mathematically (nor am I sure it's actually the correct explanation).

Where did you get these equations from? The transmission coefficient for tunneling under WKB approximation depends on both the mass of the particle and the size of the potential barrier as $e^{-\sqrt{m}d}$, so large $m$ and $d$ involve extremely small transmission coefficients.

I'm not asking about tunneling through a barrier. I'm asking about a step potential (where half of the universe is at a potential of 0 and the other half at potential V). The equations come from here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_potential#Transmission_and_reflection
"k" in my equation is just k1/k2 in Wikipedia's.

@agaminon https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2016/2cfb1c11b0f9093bb8b452c5cebf24dd_MIT8_04S16_LecNotes16.pdf The expression he gave for the transmission coefficient matches the one given in the link above.

Reflection from a potential lower than the energy level of a particle is an interference effect. When information is copied out of a system during interference the interference is suppressed. This effect is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
There are papers that have discussed the suppression of reflection by decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3377
Reflection is suppressed by the action of decoherence on the target of the scattering target but not by decoherence of the incoming particle.

I'm not asking about tunneling. I'm asking about a step potential with E>V. It's the reflection that should be suppressed here.

@PhysicsGuy I changed the answer to explain what happens in the case of reflection.
